# IUnityContainer.Resolve<T> throws error claiming it cannot be used with type parameters

Tags: c#, .net, generics, unity-container, compilation

Yesterday I've implemented the code:

```
CustomerProductManager productsManager = container.Resolve<CustomerProductManager>();
```

It was compilable and working.

Today (probably I've modified something) I am constantly getting the error:

> The non-generic method
>   'Microsoft.Practices.Unity.IUnityContainer.Resolve(System.Type,
>   string, params
>   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolverOverride[])'
>   cannot be used with type arguments

My collegue has the same source code and doesn't have same error. Why? How to resolve the problem?

P.S.

line "using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;" is present in usings section.

I've tried to replace generic version with non-generic one:

```
CustomerProductManager productsManager = (CustomerProductManager)container.Resolve(typeof(CustomerProductManager));
```

And got another error:

> No overload for method 'Resolve' takes
>   '1' arguments

It seems like one of the assemblies is not referenced.. but which one? I have 2 of them referenced:
1. Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll
2. Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll

P.P.S. I've saw similar problem http://unity.codeplex.com/WorkItem/View.aspx?WorkItemId=8205 but it is resolved as "not a bug"

Any thought will be helpful

Comment: Are you using Unity 2.0?

Comment: You'll probably find that it's the Power Commands add-on that's removing unused namespace using clauses; the namespace is "unused" when your code is in an uncompilable state and you probably have a habit of saving the file during editing--and the add-on removes the extra uses when saving.

Answer (score 176):

I had the same problem and found the "fix" looking at Prism sample code files. Looks like, even if it is not a dll in Unity V2 you have to add a reference in your class to:
**Microsoft.Practices.Unity**

my complete "using" section is as follow

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Modularity;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;
using Microsoft.Practices.Composite.UnityExtensions;
```

I'm not sure if you are using Silverlight, but the generic version for Container.Resolve  **IS** in Microsoft.Practices.Unity.

Comment: Exactly. Some time ago I've detected that adding 'using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;' resolves an issue.

Comment: This worked me also, but damn resharper is now moaning about unused 'using directives.'

Comment: The reason is that Resolve with a type parameter is an extension method found in Microsoft.Practices.Unity, while the Resolve() without a type parameter is just a method on the interface (or class).

Comment: Thx! All these years later and this just happened on brand new code. HttpClient is the same way with these 'hidden' extension secrets. Not a fan. I like Simple Injector.

Comment: Worked for me. Weird thing was I could go to the definition fine but the using statement wasn't there.

Comment: And FWIW, in the new and supposedly highly compatible Unity 5, the namespace is now `Unity` and not `Microsoft.Practices.Unity`.

Comment: Thx Ken, you saved me a ton of time trying to track this down. Upgraded my Unity nuget package and this no longer worked until just changing to using Unity like you mentioned

Comment: Thanks, I was totally confused with -  Resolve(Type type, string name, params ResolverOverride[] overrides)

Answer (score 49):

Microsoft no longer owns Unity and it's in version 5, the namespace is now:

```
using Unity;
```

Ensure that is in your using section when using:

```
container.Resolve<T>();
```

Comment: Note that in case you're using Prism, the current stable version (6.3.0) of Prism _still_ uses Unity 4.0.1, where you still have to `using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;`

Comment: Seriously, this one was driving me nuts.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem and none of this answers did not help me. I was getting the compile time error

> Unknown method RegisterType() of
>   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.IUnityContainer

for my below code.

`Container.RegisterType<IMyInterface, MyClass>();`

I found that if you did not implement `IMyInterface` to the class `MyClass`, you get this issue.
Hope it resolves for you too...

Answer (score 0):

In my situation the class I was wrapping with Unity inherited from an abstract base class, and that base class did **NOT** have a parameterless constructor.  Once I changed my code to use a parameterless constructor for the base class, the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, I had Bootstrapper implement its own Resolve without the generic version, so it couldn't find the Microsoft's Unity Resolve. Adding the proper usings did the trick.